# Room update based on selection

Tags: sql-update, android-room

I am using Room in my application, and I wish to update the results based on a selection with order by.
The goal is to update the five top scoring results.
Inside my Dao class I have this query:

```
    // Setting new five words
    @Query("with data as( SELECT score FROM words_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5 )" +
            " UPDATE data SET isInTodayWords= 1")
    LiveData<List<Word>> setNewWords();
```

I get an error from the update statement - "can't resolve symbol data".
What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you need to UPDATE the actual table not the CTE. Try :-

```
@Query("with data as( SELECT score FROM words_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5 )" +
            " UPDATE words_table  SET isInTodayWords= 1")
LiveData<List<Word>> setNewWords();
```

As per (qualified-table-name):-

[image]

Saying that I believe that you need to the utilise the CTA (data) in the WHERE clause otherwise all rows will be updated.

As such you likely want to add `WHERE score IN data` (see note below as this could apply, if a row has a unique column then you may prefer to extract that rather than the score and use it in the WHERE clause):-

```
@Query("WITH data AS (SELECT score FROM words_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5) UPDATE words_table SET isInTodaysWords = 1 WHERE score IN data")
```

An alternative approach could be to use :-

```
@Query("UPDATE words_table SET isInTodaysWords = 1 WHERE score >= (SELECT min(score) FROM (SELECT * FROM words_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5))")
```

- However, if there were say 10 rows all with the same topscore then all 10 rows would be flagged.
- If there was a unique column named **_id** then the following would restrict the flagging to the 5 selected rows :-

  `@Query("WITH data AS (SELECT _id FROM words_table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5) UPDATE words_table SET isInTodaysWords = 1 WHERE _id IN data")`

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Also, is there a way to run several queries inside one Dao method?

Comment: @dwylem not that i'm aware of.